# Bootstrap carousel won't slide when adding dynamic data

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I added data from database but they show separately and won't change or slide as they should. I tried using some JavaScript but couldn't make it work. If i use the carousel-item on my class it makes it worse. Therefore I am following this link as they use item. Below is a picture to show you what i am trying to implement.

//html page

```
 {{Form::open(array('action'=>'HomeController@show_news', 'id'=>'myform'))}}
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <?php if (isset($news)) { $i=0; ?>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            @foreach ($news as $row)
                <div class="item active" onclick="javascript:getimageid('{{$row->id}}')">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode($row->img_png)}}">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4><a href="#">{{$row->title}}</a></h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach ($news as $rows)
                <?php $i++ ?>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{$i}}" class="list-group-item">
                    <h4>{{$rows->title}}</h4>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
        <input name="post_id[]" id="post_id[]" type="hidden">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getimageid(id) {
                $('[id^=post_id]').val(id);
                document.getElementById('myform').submit();
            }
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                    interval: 1000
                })
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="carousel-controls">
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
```

//css style

```
#myCarousel .carousel-caption {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    text-shadow:none;

}

#myCarousel .list-group {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 33.5%;
}
#myCarousel .list-group-item {
    border-radius:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#myCarousel .list-group .active {
    background-color:#eee;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #myCarousel {padding-right:33.3333%;}
    #myCarousel .carousel-controls {display:none;}
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .carousel-caption p,
    #myCarousel .list-group {display:none;}
}
```

[image]

[image]

//after changing item to carousel-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel component expects one and only one **active** element.

Try something like this:

```
@foreach ($news as $index => $row)
    <div class="item <?php if ($index == 0) echo "active"; ?>" onclick="javascript:getimageid('{{$row->id}}')">
```

That should make the first item active and hide the other images.

---

### Previous Answer

It looks like you are missing several necessary css classes. At the very least, you should add the `carousel` and `slide` classes to the form element (and you should probably use a `div` instead of a `form` container unless you have a compelling reason to do so). Also, the items in the carousel should have class `carousel-item` instead of `item`.

Replacing the first line with `{{Form::open(array('action'=>'HomeController@show_news', 'id'=>'myform', 'class'=>'carousel slider'))}}` and the item element with `<div class="carousel-item active" onclick="javascript:getimageid('{{$row->id}}')">` should make it behave like a carousel.

Try to make it look as much like [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#with-captions) as possible.

Comment: thank you for answer. I took this snippet from this link https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/news-carousel

when l try to load images from database it shows all pictures but not in slider.
I do have the form you mentioned.

Comment: Can you post your updated code showing the edits I suggested? Adding the `carousel` and `slide` classes to the `{{Form}}` should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried you idea but it just makes it worse, can you please check the whole code again?

Comment: How did it make it worse? Can you provide a screenshot of what it is actually displaying?

Comment: It just displays all pictures in the while screen... no design!

Comment: check the answer

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's console? It could be because bootstrap css or js is not being loaded correctly.

Comment: CSS and JS are working just fine because if l use without database it will work. It wont if i put image from database.

Comment: I updated my previous answer - it looks like it is because all of your slides have the **active** class.

Comment: With a little bit more work around with your answer finally now is working. Thanks man.